# Java Time Conversion

Tags: java

So I am trying to convert a TimeStamp, stored in UTC back into the appropriate times based on three separate time zones. I have a good start but cannot seem to find a way to get a simple answer. I need the conversion to populate a ComboBox.

To boil it down I have this:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = 2018-05-18T15:00-04:00[America/New_York]
```

All I need is an easy way to get 11 or 11:00 out of this particular example. Basically I need to perform the actual offset operation. It seems like this part should be easy but I cannot figure it out. thanks.

Comment: Why do you expect 11:00 in your example? Shouldn't the UTC time be 19?

Comment: I think 11:00 will be UTC+4

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-05-18T15:00+04:00");
LocalTime time = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalTime();
```

Although the `time` variable value will be 19:00, not 11:00 since you are using UTC-4 timezone.

Answer (score 0):

So, I some what confused as to your overall issues

> So I am trying to convert a TimeStamp, stored in UTC back into the appropriate times based on three separate time zones

So, you have a `java.sql.TimeStamp`? Then you should be able to use something like...

```
ZonedDateTime utcDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(ts.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```

To get the UTC based value

From there you just need to convert the `utcDateTime` to a `LocalDateTime` for the specific time zone

```
// This is just for testing, you can use the previous result instead
ZonedDateTime utcDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
LocalDateTime localDateTime = utcDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();

System.out.println("utcDateTime = " + utcDateTime);
System.out.println("localDateTime = " + localDateTime);
```

Which, for me, prints

```
utcDateTime = 2018-05-18T08:36:46.808Z[UTC]
localDateTime = 2018-05-18T18:36:46.808
```

You can then apply what ever formatting you want to the `LocalDateTime`, for example...

```
System.out.println(localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")));
```

which prints...

```
18:36
```

Now, obviously, I'm just using my local time zone, but the concept will work for any specified time zone instead

For example, I tested...

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = utcDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC-4")).toLocalDateTime();
```

which should be the time zone for New York and it outputted...

```
utcDateTime = 2018-05-18T08:43:58.995Z[UTC]
localDateTime = 2018-05-18T04:43:58.995
04:43
```